Delayed server responses when logged in to wordpress admin on one browser (any browser!) for a while
This issue sounds kind of ridiculous, but I’ve pinned it down as best I can and ruled out anything obvious.
When I’ve been logged in as admin and working on my site in a browser for a while (“a while” is variable, but maybe half an hour to a few hours), it starts to get extremely slow to load any public or admin page. Using developer tools I can see that the slowdown is caused by huge delays in “waiting for server response” – up to 60s for even small and simple resources. This means a single page can end up taking several minutes to load, and sometimes the browser gives up entirely and times it out.
But these server delays are localised to my current login. I can fix the delay locally by:

Switching to a different browser. (Note: this issue is not specific to a particular browser. If I use firefox for a while it slows down and switching to chrome speeds back up again. If I use chrome for a while it slows down and switching to firefox speeds back up again.)

Clearing my browser cache and history.

Logging in again in an incognito window.

Switching to a different user account on my device.

Giving up for a while and coming back later (without logging out or anything else in between).


Here’s a recording that shows the homepage taking over two minutes to load in chrome, then immediately switching to a firefox window and loading the same page in a few seconds. (Note again, this issue is not specific to chrome, it is specific to whichever browser I have been logged in on and using). https://streamable.com/qadvcy
Things I’ve ruled out:

The slowdown is not an overall server performance issue. If I do a lighthouse report of the public homepage during a slowdown it gives normal results.

I’ve deactivated all plugins with no change.

I’ve enabled and disabled bluehost’s server-side caching with no change.

The issue has been going on for a few months, across various wordpress and plugin updates, but it’s taken me a while to pin it down.


And an additional factor: I have two separate wordpress installs on the same shared hosting, one as a subdomain of the other. They both display this same issue. And I think (but am not 100% certain yet) that a local slowdown on one usually or always causes a local slowdown on the other.
I just have no idea where to go from here. I'm not even sure whether this question counts as on-topic here, because I don't know if it's a programming problem or not.

It’s not a browser issue because it’s not specific to a particular browser. Except it kind of is a browser issue because it’s specific to whichever browser I’ve been using each time.

It’s not a wordpress installation issue because the same thing happens across multiple installs on the same server. Except it kind of is a wordpress issue because it specifically happens when I am logged in and performing admin actions.

It’s not a server issue because it’s local to my device. Except it kind of is a server issue because the slowdown is specifically caused by delayed server responses.


What could be causing this, and how can I fix it?

Are you able to replicate the issue on localhost? And have you contacted the host? Maybe it’s a bug and a simple server restart on their end will solve the issue. (Switching hosts is of course also a good though time-consuming debugging step.)

Also: check the http headers and compare the initial quick response to slower ones. Might have to do with something like cookies or redirects.

Last advice: an experienced developer might be able to pinpoint the problem quite easily, so consider hiring one. Or ask a friend (of a friend) with knowledge of programming who might be able solve this. Your question is too vague and entirely non-reproducible, so I would be surprised if someone on this forum could give you the solution.

Slow WordPRess admin when switching browser can be related to Browse Happy API checks. WordPress checks user browser to make sure that admin area User Interface is fully functional for your browser. It is very old way of checking for not compatible browsers.
Usually these check sare fast like 1 second. But temporarily it may get slow or your web server may have some network problem.
To isolate problem and to make sure that it is related to API calls (external requests made using WP_HTTP) instal either:

"Query monitor" plugin to view exactly why page is slow while you are viewing pages. it shows database, plugin, WP_HTTP usage.

"HTTP Requests Manager" plugin to log all WP_HTTP requests with request time and total page generation time. It  will record on all pages even if you log out or switch browsers.  If it is Browse Happy API issue then you can block it selecting "Smart Block" mode. Additionally it block self pings, enclosure checks, any external request on slow pages etc.


I had similar issue when I first login to admin or when I edit couple posts my WordPress will become very slow. Sometime it will show 504 error. "Smart block" fixed my issue.
Regards.
